# How to complete windows upgrade when stuck on white screen without access to anything?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

My mom tried to complete the latest windows 11 upgrade on her own, and when I got here, she was stuck on this screen. I can't access the start menu or the task manager, because the dialog is full screen and always on top. Alt-tabbing doesn't help either. If I alt-tab to task manager, it is placed behind the upgrade dialog.
[image]

Comment: Try Ctrl Al Del   ..  Launch Task Manager so you can see it. See if you can kill the update task.  Beware that may have unintended consequences.

Comment: @John I tried that. Task manager just gets placed behind the upgrade dialog.

Comment: You may have to force the computer OFF and hope for the best.   Push and hold the power button until the computer turns OFF.  Then start up and see what happens.

Comment: @John Yes, a restart fixed it. My mom had previously just pulled the plug, so I assumed that a restart wouldn't help. But it did. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stuck on this screen. I can't access the start menu or the task
> manager, because the dialog is full screen and always on top

If you cannot open anything, not even Task Manager from Ctrl Alt Del, then the only recourse is to shut down.

Push and hold the power button until the machine shuts down.

Wait 60 seconds.

Start up and see if the machine runs.

This procedure normally works - I have used it.